# How to best join baseboard to tile trim on wall?

Tags: tiling, skirting

The tile installer ran the tile trim all the way to the floor.

I need to reinstall the skirting board, but am unsure of the best way to join it up with the new tile trim.

What are my options?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*This is more a matter of opinion than anything where one way is clearly best.*

I'd likely mitre the end of the board, and trim so the end of the mitre was the same thickness as the tile trim, and either butt them together or leave a gap and caulk it.

Comment: By "mitre the end", do you mean a return to the wall? 90 degrees or 45?

Comment: This is what I do as well. I personally think it looks a little nicer to butt them rather than leaving the gap, but you decide what looks best for you.

Comment: @isherwood 45 leaving the small end of the 45 the same thickness as the tile.

Comment: Exactly what I had in mind, though that's not entirely clear in your answer. Miter returns are a somewhat advanced technique (not complicated, but not commonly understood) that calls for more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I’d treat the vertical trim like vertical trim on doors and extend it to the floor. Then, butt the base trim into it.

The vertical trim needs to be slightly thicker anyway, so that it can be dadoed to fit over the edge of the tile.

Comment: it looks like it already has a schluter trim running down to the floor. I agree butt the base into the schluter trim.